# How to search for a variable in a list of strings

Tags: python

I have very basic python knowledge. This is my code so far: 
when i run this code the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment on line 7` displays. I am trying to create a function that compares the response input to two lists and if that input is found true or false is assigned to response. I also need to assign response, which should be true or false to another list of answers. (true or false will be assigned values and the total of the list of answers will be calculated to match a final list calculation).

```
response = [str(input("Would you rather eat an apple or an orange? Answer apple or orange."))]
list1 =[str("apple"), str("Apple"), str("APPLE")]
lsit3 = [str("an orange"), str("Orange"), str("orange"), str("an Orange"), str("ORANGE")]

def listCompare():
 for list1[0] in list1:
    for response[0] in response:
      if response[0] == list1[0]:
        response = true
      else:
        for list3[0] in list3:
          for response[0] in response:
            if response[0] == list3[0]:
              response = false
listCompare()
```

**EDIT: Ok. Thanks for the roast. I'm in highschool and halfway through an EXTREMELY basic class. I'm just trying to make this work to pass. I dont need "help" anymore.

Comment: In addition, your knowledge of Python is less than what you would know after going through a beginner's tutorial. `for list1[0] in list1` is syntactically correct, but produces very... interesting results. Maybe read a tutorial first, there are so many more issues in your code other than the `UnboundLocalError` it produces that I really don't know where to start.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Comment: `response` is a global, but you haven't declared it as global in your function. And like timgeb said, that's only one of many, many issues in your code. There are so many odd choices and problems in the small amount of code you've provided, that I think you're probably best off taking a very, very basic Python tutorial before even really continuing.

Comment: You should also probably pass the response to the function as well. You can read global variables in a function, but you are not allowed assign to them without using the ``global`` keyword first.

Comment: Really, you need to learn the basic syntactic and data elements before you try to write this much code at once.  For instance, you try to use the variable **response** for three *different* purposes at once.

Answer (score 2):

You are complicating things a lot here, but that is understandable if you are new to programming or python.

To put you on the right track, this is a better way to attack the problem:

```
valid_responses = ['a', 'b']
response = input("chose a or b: ").lower().strip()
if response in valid_responses:
    print("Valid response:", response)
else:
    print("Invalid response:", response)
```

Look up any function you don't understand here.

String declarations can also just be in single or double quotes:

```
my_strings = ['orange', "apple"]
```

Also to make global variables assignable inside a function you need to use the global keyword.

```
my_global = "hello"

def my_fuction():
    global my_global
    # Do stuff with my_global
```

For loops should assign to new local variables:

```
options = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for opt in options:
    print(opt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enumerating a list of exact possible answers, you could instead match against patterns of possible answers. Here is one way to do that, case insensitively:

```
import re

known_fruits = ['apple', 'orange']
response = str(input("What would you like to eat? (Answer " + ' or '.join(known_fruits) + '): '))

def listCompare():
    for fruit in known_fruits:
        pattern = '^(?:an\s)?\s*' + fruit + '\s*$'
        if re.search(pattern,response,re.IGNORECASE):
            return True

if listCompare():
    print("Enjoy it!")
else:
    print("'%s' is an invalid choice" % response)
```

This would match `apple`, `Apple`, or even `ApPle`. It would also match 'an apple'. However, it would not match `pineapple`.

Here is the same code, with the regular expression broken down:

```
import re

known_fruits = ['apple', 'orange']

print("What would you like to eat?")

response = str(input("(Answer " + ' or '.join(known_fruits) + '): '))

# Change to lowercase and remove leading/trailing whitespace
response = response.lower().strip()

def listCompare():
    for fruit in known_fruits:
        pattern = (
                  '^'     + # Beginning of string
                  '('     + # Start of group
                    'an'  + #    word "an"
                    '\s'  + #    single space character
                  ')'     + # End of group
                  '?'     + # Make group optional
                  '\s*'   + # Zero or more space characters
                  fruit   + # Word inside "fruit" variable
                  '\s*'   + # Zero or more space characters
                  '$'       # End of the string
                  )
        if re.search(pattern,response):
            return True

if listCompare():
    print("Enjoy it!")
else:
    print("'%s' is an invalid choice" % response)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how productive it is to introduce ``re`` to someone who first need to grasp the basic syntax of the language :)

Comment: @Grimmy True, but it may be productive for someone Googling for "find variable in list of strings". This provides a totally different way to solve it.

Comment: And, no one really wants lists like `list3 = ['orange', 'orangE', 'oranGe', 'oranGE', 'oraNge', 'oraNgE', 'oraNGe', 'oraNGE', 'orAnge', 'orAngE', 'orAnGe', 'orAnGE', 'orANge', 'orANgE', 'orANGe', 'orANGE', 'oRange', 'oRangE', 'oRanGe', 'oRanGE', 'oRaNge', 'oRaNgE', 'oRaNGe', 'oRaNGE', 'oRAnge', 'oRAngE', 'oRAnGe', 'oRAnGE', 'oRANge', 'oRANgE', 'oRANGe', 'oRANGE', 'Orange', 'OrangE', 'OranGe', 'OranGE', 'OraNge', 'OraNgE', 'OraNGe', 'OraNGE', 'OrAnge', 'OrAngE', 'OrAnGe',  ....  'ORANGe', 'ORANGE' ]`

Comment: haha. yeah, it's a completely valid solution, but you can achieve the same with ``lower()``. I do love my ``re`` though!